# Elixir Macros: convert atoms into vars

Tags: macros, elixir

I want to create an Elixir macro that converts a list of atoms [:a, :b] to vars a, b. The value of a and b can be anything -- all that I want to achieve is creating a variable with the readable name of the atom passed in. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: One thing--why did you tag this with Erlang?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done using [`Macro.var/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#var/2)